# SharePoint 2019 On Prem - Modern experience - Conditional Formatting not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, modern-experience, 2019, json-formatting, column-formatting

Environment: SharePoint 2019 On Premise

Requirement: If a Number column value is equal to **0** then set **sp-field-severity--good** else set **sp-field-severity--warning**

Trial:
Based on the article at [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) have prepared and set the below JSON

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json",             
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField <= 0,'sp-field-severity--good', 'sp-field-severity--warning')"
  }
}
```

However it doesn't work.

I tried to check the DOM it shows as bellow

[image]

Note: As per the instructions in MS article I am using https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json schema as it is SP 2019 On Prem.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Excel-style expressions begin with an equal (`=`) are only available in SharePoint Online (**not** in SharePoint 2019).

In SharePoint 2019, you have to use the [Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#abstract-syntax-tree-expressions).

So try using below JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "class": {
      "operator": "?",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "<=",
          "operands": [
            "@currentField",
            0
          ]
        },
        "sp-field-severity--good",
        "sp-field-severity--warning"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can change the inner operator (`<=`) as per your requirements/conditions.
For Example: To set the `class` attribute if number column value is equal to 0, use:

```
"class": {
  "operator": "?",
  "operands": [
    {
      "operator": "==",
      "operands": [
        "@currentField",
        0
      ]
    },
    "sp-field-severity--good",
    "sp-field-severity--warning"
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thankx a ton. It worked like a charm :)

Comment: Hi Ganesh, how can i generate AST for a condition which has 3 options. That is If a=='1' then abc else if a=='2' the def and else if a=='3' then xyz

Comment: You need to add multiple blocks of operator & operands. Check [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) & [List formatting samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-list-formatting/) for more information.