# Applying JSON column formatting hides column list values

Tags: sharepoint-server, modern-experience, 2019, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm just getting into column formatting.  I'm trying to create the ["Create clickable actions" example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#create-clickable-actions) that was on Microsoft's site explaining Column Formatting in Modern SharePoint Sites using  JSON.   the example itself is very straight forward, but when I apply it all values in the column disappear.  There were values in the column before applying the formatting.

I tried to recreate the same formatting on my Office Developer SharePoint subscription and I had no issues applying and seeing the formatting.

Any suggestions why I wouldn't be able to apply column formatting on an on-premise 2019 server, but I can apply it to an SP online list?

I did update the schema to account for SP 2019 as specified in the documentation (`"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json"`)

Below is the JSON for the column formatting.  I've also tried to change `@currentField` to `[$Stocks]` (the internal name of the column) without success:

```
 {
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "='http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + @currentField"
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your current JSON code to your question? It will be easier to answer by looking at the JSON.

Comment: Absolutely.  I've added it to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Excel-style expressions begin with an equal (`=`) are only available in SharePoint Online (**not** in SharePoint 2019).

In SharePoint 2019, you have to use the [Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#abstract-syntax-tree-expressions).

So try using below JSON:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": {
          "operator": "+",
          "operands": [
              "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",
              "@currentField"
          ]
      }
   }
}
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint 2019 On Prem - Modern experience - Conditional Formatting not working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293527/sharepoint-2019-on-prem-modern-experience-conditional-formatting-not-working/293529#293529)

Comment: Fantastic!!  Works like I originally hoped it would!